# php - preg_replace to highlight formatted phone numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm having a hard time trying to highlight a search result for a formatted phone number.

```
$search_txt='5678'; // user generated (can be anything)
$phone_number='(123) 456-7890'; // always in this format
```

I'm trying this to get the highlighted string:

```
$highlighted = preg_replace('#'. preg_quote($search_txt) .'#i', '<span style="background-color:#ff0;">\\0</span>', $phone_number);
```

The `$search_txt` could be anything. "7890" works, "456-7890", works, but "5678" doesn't work due to the "-" in `$phone_number`.

I've also tried stripping the format of `$phone_number` (i.e. "1234567890"), but if they enter alpha characters "56-78", I have the same issue.

If I strip both `$phone_number` ("1234567890") and `$search_txt` ("5678"), the highlighting works and returns `1234<span style="background-color:#ff0;">5678</span>90`, but I don't know how to re-introduce the formatting with the highlight code in the string.

The final string needs to be a phone number format "(123) 456-7890" with highlighting HTML included.

Option #1: Can I format a phone number while ignoring HTML tags within the number?

i.e. `1234<span style="background-color:#ff0;">5678</span>90`

becomes `(123) 4<span style="background-color:#ff0;">56-78</span>90`

Option #2: Can I ignore the alpha characters in `$phone_number` when matching, but include them in the replaced string?

i.e. "5678" would match "(123) 456-7890"

and return `(123) 4<span style="background-color:#ff0;">56-78</span>90`.

Comment: Save the number in its original format in one variable then strip the dashes in another variable. Do the comparison and return the original as the highlighted number.

Comment: I'm also trying to highlight the search term ("56-78") in the formatted number (when they search "5678"). The original needs to be partially highlighted (not the entire string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your  tags have no numeric values as a clear example:

`$phone = "1234<span>5678</span>90";
$pattern = '/(\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d)(\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d)(\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*)/';
$replace = '($1) $2-$3';
echo "\n\n".preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $phone);`

produces:

`(123) 4<span>56-78</span>90`

basically I'm capturing zero-or-more of non-numeric values before each digit and once after the last.  This assumes you have reduced both the search string and the target phone number to simple number strings ("4567" and "1234567890") and then performed your search-and-replace to place the HTML tags.

If you must have numbers in your HTML tags, then you must replace \D with something like <[^>]*>.

`$pattern = '/((?:<[^>]*>)*\d(?:<[^>]*>)*\d(?:<[^>]*>)*\d)...`

The (?:...) construct groups items without capturing them.  Use the {} construct to add a bit of elegance and you have:

`$pattern = '/((?:(?:<[^>]*>)*\d){3})((?:(?:<[^>]*>)*\d){3})((?:(?:<[^>]*>)*\d){4}(?:<[^>]*>)*)/';`

Comment: One note about `$replace`. I was getting `\(123\)` in my results, so I removed the slashes. `$replace = '($1) $2-$3';`  - Thanks for the help.

Comment: Duh.  Thanks Rev.  Sometimes you just can't see the trees for the forest.  I changed the post.

Comment: This is incredible, thank you! Converted it to JS for my proj & it's working perfectly.